# Create list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I have the variables in the below format.

```
 x = 0,
 y =  numpy.array([[5, 7, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
 z = 2
```

I would like to create a list of tuples in [(x,y,z)] format as below.

```
[(0,5,2), (0,7,2), (0,11,2), (0,12,2), (0,13,2), (0,14,2)]
```

Comment: What was the difficulty when you tried to write the code for this? Have you tried to write a `for` loop?

Comment: Hi, I need to create the tuples for all the combinations in x, y, z. Since, I am completely new to python, I got stuck on how to create it. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try anything at all?

Comment: Did you read the official Python tutorial already?

Comment: I got the basics understanding on Python. Since, I got stuck here while programming, thought of seeking help from the experts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = 0
y = [5, 7, 11, 12, 13, 14]
z = 2
list1 = [(x, item ,z) for item in y ]
print(list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should not be a difficult task. You don't need to use numpy as well.

```
x = 0
y = [5, 7, 11, 12, 13, 14]
z = 2
output = []
for i in y:
   output.append((x,i,z))
```